# Flutter Firestore Issue: Not able to store Sign Up form data in Cloud Firestore DB, instead hard coded data is getting stored

Tags: forms, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, null, storage

**DatabaseService Class**

```
class DatabaseService {

  final String uid;
  DatabaseService({this.uid});

 //collection reference
  final CollectionReference agentsCollection = 
        Firestore.instance.collection('agents');

 Future updateUserData( 
                        String fullname, 
                        String phonenumber, 
                        String email, 
                        String profession, 
                        String city
                      ) 
async {
   return await agentsCollection.document(uid).setData({

       'fullname': fullname,
       'phonenumber': phonenumber,
       'email': email,
       'profession': profession,
       'city': city,


    });
   }
```

**AuthService Class**

```
class AuthService {

final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

//create user object based on FirebaseUser
User _userFromFirebaseUser(FirebaseUser user) {
  return user != null ? User(uid: user.uid) : null;
}

//auth change user stream
Stream<User> get user {
  return _auth.onAuthStateChanged
      .map(_userFromFirebaseUser);
}

Then I have a function to Register the user in this class as below:

//Register with email and password

Future registerWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password) async {

  try{

     AuthResult result = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword
     (email: email, password: password);   
     FirebaseUser user = result.user;

//create a new document for the user with the uid
     await DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).updateUserData( 'hardcoded Name', 
     'Hardcoded Number','hardcoded email', 'hardcoded profession', 'hardcoded city'); 

     return _userFromFirebaseUser(user);

  } catch(e){
      print(e.toString());
      return null;

  }
}
```

**SignUp Class**

In this class I call the user (uid) using Provider service. Then I use the function from the AuthService Class which uses the function from the DatabaseService class in order to create a new document in the Database.

```
RaisedButton(
       elevation: 5.0,
       padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 60, right: 60 , top: 15, bottom:15),
            color: Colors.blue,
            child: Text(
              'Sign Up',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),

     onPressed: () async {

           if(_formKey.currentState.validate()){
           setState(() => loading= true); 

           dynamic result = await _auth.registerWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);    

            await DatabaseService (uid: user.uid).updateUserData(this.fullname, 
            this.phonenumber, this.email, this.profession, this.city);

            if(result == null) {
               setState(() {
                 error = 'please supply a valid email';
                  loading = false;
               });
            } else {

                 Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(
                   builder: (context) => SignIn()
                ));

           }
         }
       }
     ),
```

So Given all this, for some reason it's only storing the hard coded data from the AuthService class and not performing the line in the SignUp class under the onPressed() function; where I am telling it to use the function updateUserData and store the this.email, this.fullname, etc. Also an important note, in the SignUp class it says returned null user (assuming uid).

Please someone help me if you get what I am doing wrong in this context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey @Ggriffo i used this code in the onPressed function:

```
dynamic result = await _auth.registerWithEmailAndPassword
        (email, password).then((user) {    
        DatabaseService (uid: user.uid).updateUserData(this.fullname, 
        this.phonenumber, this.email, this.profession, this.city);
         });
```

and now it works! i used this logic from your onPressed piece of code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think when parsing the data the hard coded data remains. here is an example of how to fix it.

create a user obj

```
class User {
  final String userID;
  final String displayName;
  final String email, pushToken;
  final String phoneNumber;
  final String profilePictureURL;

  User({
    this.phoneNumber,
    this.userID,
    this.pushToken,
    this.displayName,
    this.email,
    this.profilePictureURL,
  });

  Map<String, Object> toJson() {
    return {
      'pushToken': pushToken,
      'phoneNumber': phoneNumber,
      'userID': userID,
      'displayName': displayName,
      'email': email == null ? '' : email,
      'profilePictureURL': profilePictureURL,
      'appIdentifier': 'my app'
    };
  }

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, Object> doc) {
    User user = new User(
      pushToken: doc['pushToken'],
      userID: doc['userID'],
      displayName: doc['displayName'],
      phoneNumber: doc['phoneNumber'],
      email: doc['email'],
      profilePictureURL: doc['profilePictureURL'],
    );
    return user;
  }

  factory User.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    return User.fromJson(doc.data);
  }
}
```

and then the sign up method

```
//user sign up
     static Future<String> signUp(String email, String password) async {
        final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
        FirebaseUser user = (await _firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                email: email, password: password))
            .user;

        return user.uid;
      }
 //if user id doesnt exist add user 
    static void addUser(User user) async {
        checkUserExist(user.userID).then((value) {
          if (!value) {
            print("user ${user.displayName} ${user.email} added");

            Firestore.instance
                .document("users/${user.userID}")
                .setData(user.toJson());

            Fluttertoast.showToast(
                msg: "user ${user.displayName} ${user.email} added");
          } else {
            print("user ${user.displayName} ${user.email} exists");
          }
        });
      }
//check if user exists    
      static Future<bool> checkUserExist(String userID) async {
        bool exists = false;
        try {
          await Firestore.instance.document("users/$userID").get().then((doc) {
            if (doc.exists)
              exists = true;
            else
              exists = false;
          });
          return exists;
        } catch (e) {
          return false;
        }
      }
```

and to handle your button onPressed: and it will save your data to firestore

```
await signUp(email, password).then((uID) {
          addUser(new User(
              userID: uID,
              email: email,
              displayName: fullname,
              phoneNumber: number,
              pushToken: pushToken,
              profilePictureURL: ''));
```

Comment: Hi @griffo, this doesn't work for me. Any other solutions?

Comment: At this moment no..this is what I used in a recent project. Should I find another way I'll update my answer